# MapReduce HBase NullPointerException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am beginner at bigdata. First I wanna try how mapreduce work with hbase. The scenario is  summing of a field uas in my hbase use map reduce based on date which is as primary key. Here is my table :

> Hbase::Table - test
>    ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL
>    10102010#1                                 column=cf:nama, timestamp=1418267197429,  value=jonru
>    10102010#1                                 column=cf:quiz, timestamp=1418267197429, value=\x00\x00\x00d
>    10102010#1                                 column=cf:uas, timestamp=1418267197429, value=\x00\x00\x00d
>    10102010#1                                 column=cf:uts, timestamp=1418267197429, value=\x00\x00\x00d
>    10102010#2                                 column=cf:nama, timestamp=1418267180874, value=jonru
>    10102010#2                                 column=cf:quiz, timestamp=1418267180874, value=\x00\x00\x00d
>    10102010#2                                 column=cf:uas, timestamp=1418267180874, value=\x00\x00\x00d
>    10102010#2                                 column=cf:uts, timestamp=1418267180874, value=\x00\x00\x00d
>    10102012#1                                 column=cf:nama, timestamp=1418267156542, value=jonru
>    10102012#1                                 column=cf:quiz, timestamp=1418267156542, value=\x00\x00\x00\x0A
>    10102012#1                                 column=cf:uas, timestamp=1418267156542, value=\x00\x00\x00\x0A
>    10102012#1                                 column=cf:uts, timestamp=1418267156542, value=\x00\x00\x00\x0A
>    10102012#2                                 column=cf:nama, timestamp=1418267166524, value=jonru
>    10102012#2                                 column=cf:quiz, timestamp=1418267166524, value=\x00\x00\x00\x0A
>    10102012#2                                 column=cf:uas, timestamp=1418267166524, value=\x00\x00\x00\x0A
>    10102012#2                                 column=cf:uts, timestamp=1418267166524, value=\x00\x00\x00\x0A

My codes are like these :

```
public class TestMapReduce {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException,  ClassNotFoundException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    Job job = new Job(config, "Test");
    job.setJarByClass(TestMapReduce.TestMapper.class);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(500);
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
            "test",
            scan,
            TestMapReduce.TestMapper.class,
            Text.class,
            IntWritable.class,
            job);

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
            "test",
            TestReducer.class,
            job);



    job.waitForCompletion(true);

 }

 public static class TestMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowKey, Result columns, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("mulai mapping");

        try {
            //get row key
            String inKey = new String(rowKey.get());
            //get new key having date only
            String onKey = new String(inKey.split("#")[0]);
            //get value s_sent column
            byte[] bUas = columns.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("uas"));
            String sUas = new String(bUas);
            Integer uas = new Integer(sUas);

            //emit date and sent values
            context.write(new Text(onKey), new IntWritable(uas));
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public class TestReducer extends TableReducer {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            int sum = 0;
            for (Object test : values) {
                System.out.println(test.toString());
                sum += Integer.parseInt(test.toString());
            }

            Put inHbase = new Put(key.getBytes());
            inHbase.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("sum"), Bytes.toBytes(sum));

            context.write(null, inHbase);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   }
```

I got errors like these :

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
                at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010) at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:451)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:424)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:656)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:745)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:728)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:421)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:348)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
                at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
                at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
                at TestMapReduce.main(TestMapReduce.java:97)
        Java Result: 1
```

Help me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this part of your code:

```
byte[] bUas = columns.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("uas"));
String sUas = new String(bUas);
```

For the current key you are trying to get a value of column *uas* from column family *cf*. This is a non-relational DB, so it is easily possible that this key doesn't have a value for this column. In that case, *getValue* method will return null. String constructor that accepts byte[] as an input can't handle null values, so it will throw a NullPointerException. A quick fix will look like this:

```
byte[] bUas = columns.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("uas"));
String sUas = bUas == null ? "" : new String(bUas);
```